# how to do Array.tryFind with index?

Tags: f#

a simple example of what I would like to do is

```
 Array.tryFind (fun elem index -> elem + index = 42) array1  //not valid
```

Since there is no `break` or `continue`, i find it hard to do it manually even in a for loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar with @gradbot's answer, you could define a module function along the line of `mapi`, `iteri` which works on arrays, lists and sequences.

```
module Seq =
    let tryFindi fn seq =
        seq |> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> i, x)
            |> Seq.tryFind (fun (i, x) -> fn i x)
            |> Option.map snd

// Usage
let res = [|1;1;40;4;2|] |> Seq.tryFindi (fun i el -> i + el = 42)
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I find something I need missing from the built in functions, I just add it!  I always have a file called `Helpers.fs` where I keep all of these.  Just make sure to give it a good name.

```
module Array =
    let tryFindWithIndex fn (array : _[]) =
        let rec find index =
            if index < array.Length then
                if fn array.[index] index then
                    Some(array.[index])
                else
                    find (index + 1)
            else
                None
        find 0
```

Example use.

```
[|1;1;40;4;2|]
|> Array.tryFindWithIndex (fun elem index -> elem + index = 42)
|> printf "%A"
```

Outputs

```
Some 40
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (disclaimer: typing in browser - may contain errors)

```
array |> Seq.mapi (fun i el -> i + el) |> Seq.tryFind ((=)42)
```